# EMACS-Python-Mode-Load Error

Tags: python, emacs

I am new to Emacs (24). I installed the python-mode. And it's path name is "~/.emacs.d/python-mode-6.0.10 " . I have a "python-settings.el" file in "~/.emacs.d/settings/", it contains the following lines,

```
   ; python-mode
   (setq py-install-directory "~/.emacs.d/python-mode-6.0.11")
   (add-to-list 'load-path py-install-directory)
   (require 'python-mode)
```

In my .emacs file I have added,

```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/settings")
   (require 'python-settings)
```

But when I try to load emacs ,I keep getting the error "Cannot Open load file "python-mode".

I don't know what's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If `M-: (require 'python-mode)` gives you an error, then python-mode.el isn't in your load path; looking at your question again, I note that in the text you mention it being in `~/.emacs.d/python-mode-6.0.10`, but your python-settings.el references `~/.emacs.d/python-mode-6.0.11` -- is it possible that's a typo in python-settings.el?

Comment: I tried this (replaced python-mode with python in my python-settings.el file),and I am getting an error telling python-settings not provided.

Comment: But why I should I use (require 'python) when I have specifically installed the python-mode package and put it in '~/.emacs.d/python-mode-6.0.11 ' . This uses ipython and I want emacs to be configured so that I can access the ipython interpreter from within emacs.

Comment: The argument passed to REQUIRE isn't a filename, but rather a symbol which matches one passed to PROVIDE in the code you're trying to load -- if `python-mode.el` includes `(provide 'python)`, then the correct form of the REQUIRE call is `(require 'python)`, with the same symbol as passed to PROVIDE. Similarly, if you're trying to `(require 'python-settings)`, but nothing has called PROVIDE with that symbol, then you'll get an error -- add to the end of your `python-settings.el` file the form `(provide 'python-settings)`, and the REQUIRE call with that symbol will start to work.

Comment: Ok ,I added (provide 'python-settings) at the end of my python-settings.el file . Now , I don't get any error. But looks like nothing has changed , I am not able to access the IPython interpreter with C-c ! and EMACS is not auto-indenting my python files. I don't see any change . It is exactly like how it was before I installed python-mode.

Comment: @user1955184 Per Andreas Röhler's answer, it looks like I was barking up the wrong tree; `(require 'python-mode)` is correct for the mode you're trying to use, and apologies for the error. If `M-: (require 'python-mode)` gives you an error, then python-mode.el isn't in your load path; looking at your question again, I note that in the text you mention it being in ~/.emacs.d/python-mode-6.0.10, but your python-settings.el references ~/.emacs.d/python-mode-6.0.11 -- is it possible that's a typo in python-settings.el?

Comment: Yes. I don't understand why it is not in my load-path. I have loaded the path of my settings folder ,the folder where I keep my python-settings. Now I require this python-settings.el in my .emacs file. This python-settings.el requires python-mode.el and adds other settings required for ipython to work properly. The thing is instead of directly requiring python-mode.el in my .emacs file ,I am requiring another file which in-turn requires that file. I don't want to load all the settings in my main .emacs file. That is why I have kept the settings in a separate folder ~/.emacs.d/settings

Comment: @user1955184 Sure. But the point I'm making is that, if python-mode.el were in the directory that python-settings.el adds to your load path, then `(require 'python-mode)` wouldn't be erroring out. Can you double-check that python-mode.el is where python-settings.el expects it to be?

Comment: @user1955184 Glad to be of help! I'll edit my answer, such that it reflects what actually solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

(require 'python-mode) is right, as python-mode.el provides 'python-mode, not 'python.

Making sure your python-settings is loaded before python-mode is required, for example by a python-file, should avoid the error.

Also you might update python-mode.el, but that's rather not related.

Comment: I am sorry but can you explain a bit elaborately ? Only my python-settings is requiring python-mode and I am requiring python-settings in my .emacs file. So python-settings can't be loaded after python-mode is required right ?

Comment: @user1955184 AFAIU your settings that seems correct. Hard to tell what's wrong from here. Just an experience from my own errors: sometimes it helps to find a way for the moment, coming back at the issue some times later. As a workaround you could use (load ...) from your emacs-init.